# Need help with RX:Convert System.Diagnostics.Process.OutputDataReceived to an Observable

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive

I want to start a subprocess and watch it's redirected output. That not
a problem for me in C#, but I try to understand RX, so the game begins ...
I have a static extension method for process, which looks like this:

```
    public static IObservable<IEvent<DataReceivedEventArgs>> GetOutput(this Process that)
    {
        return Observable.FromEvent<DataReceivedEventArgs>(that, "OutputDataReceived");
    }
```

I create an observable and subscribe to it like this:

```
    Process p = ........
    var outObs = p.GetOutput();
    var outSub = outObs.Subscribe(data => Console.WriteLine(data));
```

This is not completely wrong, but I am getting:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs]
```

while I am expecting to get strings :-(

So, I think, my extensionmethod returns the wrong type.
It would be really good, if someone could explain me, what's
wong with my extension methods signature.

Thanks a lot,
++mabra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I think, my extensionmethod returns the wrong type

That's exactly it.

IEvent wraps both the `sender` and the `EventArgs` parameters of a tradition Event delegate. So you need to modify your code to look something like

```
public static IObservable<string> GetOutput(this Process that)
{
    return Observable.FromEvent<DataReceivedEventArgs>(that, "OutputDataReceived")
                     .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs.Data);
}
```

If you're using the latest Rx, then the code is a bit different

```
public static IObservable<string> GetOutput(this Process that)
{
       return Observable.FromEventPattern<DataReceivedEventArgs>(that, "OutputDataReceived")
                        .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs.Data);
}
```

the key here is to `Select` the `EventArgs` from the EventPattern/IEvent, and then grab the `Data`

Comment: Hello ! Phantastic, this works! And much thanks for the explanation, this is clear now. Rx is hard for me ;-)

Comment: Keep w/ it, it gets into your head

Comment: The last data received is always `null` - is it possible to swallow that value and instead mark the observable as closed?